# An infinite torsion group with element orders sensitive to subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Is there an infinite torsion group $G$ such that for every $H\le G$ there is some $n\in \Bbb N$ with
$$(\forall x\in  H)(x^{n}=1), ~~(\forall x\in  G\setminus H)(x^{n}\ne1)$$

Comment: Could you add something to your question to indicate where this property you are interested in came from?  It does seem interesting, so I'd appreciate knowing more about why *you* think it is interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your condition is meant to hold for *proper* subgroups $H$, then the [Prufer $p$-groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) do the trick.

However, if $H = G$ is included, then $G$ has finite exponent, so your condition forces $G$ to be finite, by the pigeon-hole principle.

Answer (score 0):

Another example would be the direct sum of cyclic groups of distinct prime order:
$$
\bigoplus_{p_i\neq p_j, i\neq j} C_{p_i}
$$
I wonder if there are any finitely-generated examples?

---

**EDIT:** As has been pointed out in the comments, this only works is $H$ is assumed to be finitely generated.

Comment: That is an interesting question! I was also wondering whether there were non-commutative examples.

Comment: @James An answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909683/tarski-monster-groups-with-more-than-one-prime), with $n$ infinite, would do it.

Comment: @user I do not understand what you mean. Do you mean *finitely generated*? If there are infinitely many $p_i$ then the group will be an infinite, infinitely-generated torsion group. Indeed, a given element will have order $\prod p_i$ where the element in the $i^{th}$ component is non-zero. This is valid because I carefully said "direct sum".

Comment: @user As I said, this is a *direct sum*, so only finitely many components are non-trivial.

Comment: I don't think your example answers the question, since although it's torsion, it contains subgroups of infinite exponent (take all factors but one).

Comment: @YCor Oh, thanks, didn't spot that!