# Tarski monster groups with more than one prime

Tags: group-theory

A [Tarski monster group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group) is an infinite, finitely generated group where every proper, non-trivial subgroup is cyclic of order $p$ for a fixed prime $p$. These were shown to exist for "large enough" $p$ in the late 70s/early 80s by Ol'shanskii.

My question is, can we let $p$ vary within in the group? More formally:

> Let $n$ be a countable cardinal number, $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\aleph_0$. For which $n$ does there exist a set of $n$ distinct primes $\mathcal{P}_n$ such that there exists a finitely generated, infinite group $T_{\mathcal{P}_n}$ where every proper, non-trivial subgroup has order $p$ for some $p\in\mathcal{P}_n$, and for every prime $p\in\mathcal{P}_n$ there exists a subgroup $S_p\leq T_{\mathcal{P}_n}$ of order $p$?

Ol'shanskii proved that such groups exist for $n=1$‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌.

Comment: I think I remember from Gromov's original paper on hyperbolic groups that the case $n=\aleph_0$ is much easier than the case $n=1$. Anyway , I'd suggest you post this on mathoverflow; most likely Mark Sapir can answer your question.

Comment: Do you mean $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{\aleph_0\}$ instead.